# How to get array from Array of objects to get a new array as <mat-autocomplete> is not working on objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I need to extract DISPLAY_NAME into a saparate array from Amenity_Listin order to work with , but its not working.

HTML

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="element.IS_EDIT" appearance="outline">
                        <input #AmenityInput type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [(ngModel)]="element.NEW_AMENITY_NAME" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class="" (optionSelected)='onSelect($event,i)'>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions | async" [value]="item">
                                {{item}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

TS-

```
    export class ViewAssignedSeatsComponent implements OnInit {
      myControl = new FormControl('');
     filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
      displayName : string[];
      
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
              console.log(this.AmenityList);
              this.displayName = this.AmenityList.map(a=>a.DISPLAY_NAME);
              console.log(this.displayName , typeof(this.displayName));// here type is always objects though I need array
              this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
                startWith(''),
                map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
              );
          
          }
     private _filter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
        return this.AmenityList.filter(option => option.DISPLAY_NAME.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
      }
onSelect(event:any, index:any){
    console.log("called", event.target.value);// here I'm getting undefined , also after search the new value is lost.
}
    }
```

> I need just filter on mat-select using mat-autocomplete. But I'm unable to get the display names in array to have them as options for
> selection and Search. I need it in this.displayNames as array of
> string type instead of object.

Attaching image for Amenity_list.

[image]

Comment: If you do `typeof []` it will say `object`, if you want to check for array do `Array.isArray([])`, Currently your code seems fine!

Comment: @NarenMurali, How to target (selectionChange) in mat-Autocomplete, if we want to perform some operation on selected input

Comment: Does this [help](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ynrnqrokppx?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts)

Comment: @NarenMurali.. Nope, I need something like, I want to pass the new selected value to Payload. Its something like on select, there should be one method that will call. I need to pass newly selected value in that like onSelect($event.target.value).

Comment: When you set the value of the `ngModel` just trigger the function also!

Comment: @NarenMurali, I'm ale to target the value but I'm loosing it after selection. I edited my code, Please have a look.